# Sorting in an Array

Tags: java, sorting

I am working on a simple data base(using a String Array) that can store just some basic information like a person's name, birthday etc... If let's say I want to sort the people by their birthday, how might I go about doing that?

I guess the question I am asking is how is it possible to access a single portion of info. from a array element. From what I understand each array element can only store -one type and -one piece of info. I basically fitted every element in my array with a single String in a specific format. If someone can just give a very basic method of going about this, that would be of great help to me.

Comment: Haven't you learnt anything about classes till now?

Comment: Using getters. Thats how you access private incapsulated data.

Comment: No, you should write a Comparator for the class that tells the sorter how to decide what the proper order should be.

Answer (score 4):

```
public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    private String name;

    public Person(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public int compareTo(Person p) {
        return this.name.compareTo(p.name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you create a `Person` class which stores all the information about a single person. Then create an array of `Person` objects and create a `Comparator` object which defines the ordering to use in `Arrays.sort()`. If you don't understand something here, start with a google search and come back with more questions!